# Shell script to extract string from a file and return the next chars until a whitespace

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

We have an application that grabs it's setup parameters from a file. I want to extract one or two statements from the startup string and present them as a nice table.

An example string would be -Dmysql.host=mysql1.company.com  but it might also be an ipaddress or a machine name and not an fqdn.

I want locate the -Dmysql.host= but return the servername.

Any tips or pointers as to how to, once I've found the string "-Dmysql.host=" in the file, show everything to the next white space would be appreciated.

Perhaps there is a better method.  I plan on running this on a dozen machines or so eventually to return a list of which application machines are configured to talk to which db machine at a glance.

Thanks you for your time.

Comment: It would seem that sed is a popular answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep mysql.host file.txt | sed -e 's/.*mysql.host=\(\S*\).*/\1/g'
```

You should end up with a value that is the value of mysql.host.  You can put the -D in the match also if you want, but I have left it out because it is a parameter to grep and you need to escape it.

Comment: You might want to escape the dot in mysql.host as dot is a regex atom in grep so would match "mysqlshost" or "mysql-host" as well as "mysql.host"

Comment: +1 good catch, although the assumption here was there would only be one occurrence in the parameters file.  If not, you might want a '| head -n 1' in there also!

Answer (score 1):

From the information given, I would go about this by first splitting everything based on whitespace, and then split those tokens based on the = sign.  Pure bash solution would be something like what follows.

```
  foo="bar=baz boo=zip"
  for keyvalue in $foo; do
     key=${keyvalue%%=*} 
     value=${keyvalue##*=}
     echo $key $value
  done
```

Since IFS is probably whitespace, the shell takes care of splitting based on the whitespace.  You can then use Parameter (Variable) Expansion to handle spiting into key / value pairs  based on the equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

How about feeding the files to good old sed:

```
$ echo foo  -Dmysql.host=mysql1.company.com -bar | grep -- "-Dmysql.host=" | sed -e 's/^.*-Dmysql.host=//' -e 's/ .*//'
mysql1.company.com
```

So in your case you'd feed it the file like so:

```
$ grep -- "-Dmysql.host=" FILENAME | sed -e 's/^.*-Dmysql.host=//' -e 's/ .*//'
```

I realize there's a grep in there that sed could handle but this is just easier to write, sed can be awkward.